# Can't find ServiceStack RequestContext

Tags: c#, memcached, servicestack

Hello i've just created a fresh Empty webApp in VS and installed the servicestack Nugets.

I was looking for caching responsed into memory(via MemCached) but in the service `Any` method i can't access to the `base.RequestContext` object.

The class DO inherit from `ServiceStack.Service` (wasn't it `ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service` before?).

```
    public class UtentiService : Service
{

    public object Get(I_Utenti request) 
    {
        var cacheKey = "myKey";

        return  base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache, cacheKey, () =>{});
    }
}
```

But i cannot access to the `base.RequestContext`. Why?

HSH, Pizza!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have just done:

> Install-Package ServiceStack

Then it will have installed [Service Stack v4](https://servicestack.net/), the new **commercial version** of ServiceStack. In which a lot of changes have been made. See [the release notes here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes).

The issue [you are seeing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#requestcontext-now-merged-into-new-irequest--iresponse-classes) is due to the refactoring of `RequestContext` now merged into new `IRequest` / `IResponse` classes.

In v4 the request is accessed using:

```
base.Request
```

---

If you want to continue using ServiceStack v3 you can do this:

> Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 3.9.71

And you will have access in the familiar way. Note that v3 remains OpenSource.
[ServiceStack v3 Documentation is now here](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was just coming back to selfAnswer me, after reading https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#whats-new-in-v4
Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Create a property with the service:

```
 public AuthenticateService AuthService
        {
            get
            {
                var _as = HostContext.ResolveService<AuthenticateService>(base.HttpContext);
                return _as;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Relevance?. What does resolving a service have to do with accessing the request context in a ServiceStack service?

Comment: I guess you gave the right answer to the wrong answer, please consider removing it if you want to start stacking reputation